# Build and debug go code skip unresolvable packages?

Tags: go, build, package, go-modules

I am trying to build this go project from the source code here:
https://github.com/zwopir/osquery_exporter

I was able to figure out how start the process to begin downloading the dependencies, but it looks like one of them is now depreciated and no longer exists.

```
$ ~ /bin/go1.17.13 get github.com/zwopir/osquery_exporter

github.com/zwopir/osquery_exporter imports
    github.com/prometheus/common/log: cannot find module providing package github.com/prometheus/common/log
```

https://github.com/prometheus/common/pull/306

Thats fine, I can use the logging package go provides `import log` is there a commandline option or flag for get that will skip the unresolvable packages and download those that can be resolved?

Comment: Run `go get github.com/prometheus/common/log@v0.26.0` (the `log` package was removed in `v0.27`) before you get `osquery_exporter`. If you want to use another log package then you will need to fork `github.com/zwopir/osquery_exporter`. Note that Go1.17 is pretty old (as is `osquery_exporter`).

Comment: yea, I realize that. It looks the most promising to update. I removed all references to "github.com/prometheus/common/log" and replaced them with "log" somehow its still trying to pull it.

Comment: Prob would help to say Im running, go mod init osquery_exporter;  go mod tidy

Comment: Have you changed the imports in subfolders and the import paths to those subfolders (e.g. `import "github.com/zwopir/osquery_exporter/collector"` to  `import "osquery_exporter/collector"`)?. It's probably worth updating your question as this is not really the same thing.